# Querying a Database for Baby Names within Popularity Range?

Tags: names

Anybody know of a place where you can query a database for baby names with certain characteristics? (Boy/girl, popularity 150-1500 in 2005, etc)

Comment: The vast majority of baby name databases I've seen let you search by gender, alphabetically, by popularity rank within a given year, or by origin.  I haven't seen any that let you drill down to the level of specificity that you seem to be looking for, although there are a plethora of custom apps, shareware, and freeware out there that are database driven, and may have the capability you're looking for.  It's a good question; I hope you get an answer. An open-source dataset that can be exported to a standard database would be a pretty neat tool!

Answer (score 8):

I guess if you want to check a single name, then [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is a good place to start. For the input `name patrick` you get various stastics regarding rank and fractions

[image]

a timeline for the fraction

[image]

estimates of age and number currently living people with this name

[image]

a plot of the age distribution

[image]

and of course the most important: celebrities with the same name

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer - and this covers global names, so has wider usefulness.

Comment: Sadly, what I'm looking for is a database that will spit out a list of all the names that meet given criteria--it's pretty easy to find this information for a single name, but mostly what I'm looking for is candidates, so not all that helpful.

Comment: checkout www.namemeababy.com

Comment: Wow, Wolfram Alpha is amazing!

Answer (score 4):

The [Social Security office](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/OACT/babynames/#ht=1) maintains a database which can be searched by name, year, gender, ranking...

For more obscure names, you can find data [here](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/OACT/babynames/limits.html).

Comment: Sadly, what I'm looking for is a database that will spit out a list of all the names that meet given criteria, and it doesn't do that--unless you're looking for top 10/100/500/1000 names in a given decade, which I'm not.

Comment: Actually, you can get the data by year, not just decade. And it is sorted by popularity and gender. It can be copied into Excel and sorted alphabetically. Popularity, gender and year are the only characteristics you mentioned. Is there something else you are looking for? Maybe you could give an example of a query you would like to be able to perform.

Comment: A list of all names with ranking between 250 and 1500 between 1890 and now that DID NOT break <75 or less in the last ten years.  The SS database doesn't spit out lists other than the premade ones you have--you're right, I could probably get it into the shape I mean, but that would be quite a bit of work (getting rid of duplicates, manually getting rid of too-high-ranking names)--hence looking for somewhere that does proper database-querying.

Answer (score 1):

"name me a baby" is very good for this. You can search for names that "begin with", "end with" or "contain" certain strings and see how popular the resulting names are. If you click on a name you can see a graph showing how the popularity has changed over time.

http://www.namemeababy.com/

Comment: This site seems to be defunct.

Answer (score 0):

For determining the gender of a name i like https://genderize.io/ which offers a web service to determine the gender of a name in different countries.